# Adding text to an already populated UITextView

Tags: ios, uitextview

Really quick, easy question.How do I add text to a UITextView, when it's already populated.

E.G., but doesn't work: _textView.text=**+**@"";

Thanks,
SebOH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
_textView.text = [_textView.text stringByAppendingString:@""]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
_textView.text = [_textView.text stringByAppendingString:@"Additional Text"];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 _textView.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",_textView.text,@"text you want to append"];
```

using above you can add the text where ever you want prefix,postfix ..